# How can I get a value from a configuarion file using Perl's Config::Simple?

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute the shell script inside perl script. I am able to execute the shell script if I manually assign the variable. But I would like to call variable outside the script which is in configuration file.

How to execute the script? Below are my sample commands.

```
my $confdir = $ENV{CFG_DIR};  ## Directory where configuration file resides 
my $configfile = 'LED.cfg';   ## Configuration file
my $LEDcfg = new Config::Simple( filename => "$confdir/$conffile" ); ## assigning the configuration file to LEDcfg file
my $ApID = $LEDcfg->param(".ApID") ## passing the parameter ApID from configuration file 
chomp ${ApID};
my $pwd = `(ApID=$ApID $path/CA.sh)`; ## running shell script by ApID parameterized => Failed
my $pwd = `(ApID=ACF_ERTF_DER $path/CA.sh)`; ## running shell script by ApID hardcoded => Succeeded
```

Value of `ApID=ACF_ERTF_DER` as mentioned in line 7. This value is called from different configuration file which I called from `$CFG_DIR/LED.cfg`.

If I comment `my $ApID` (line 4) and `my $pwd` (line 6), the job succeeds by calling the ApID directly using the last line 7 i.e. `my $pwd = (ApID=ACF_ERTF_DER $path/CA.sh);`.

I am calling the `ApID` from *LED.cfg* file to retrieve the password from shell script and connects to server. If I run the shell script manually, I get the password which is used to connect to the server.

Comment: Isn't it - `my $pwd = \`(ApID=$ApID $path/CA.sh)\`;` ?

Comment: @vkk05 - Yes. modified the question. Thanks for that. But the issue still persists.

Comment: Once you `chomp ${ApID};` what's the value of `${ApID}`? Is right parameter is been passed to your Shell script? What happens when you execute the Shell script manually by passing required args?

Comment: This is very huge script created by my organization leads. There are various steps performed by the script. However the only part which i am trying to do is, to connect to database server by running the shell script which takes the variable named ApID from another file /abcd/efgh/ijkl/LEG.cfg. I know i am doing something wrong in assigning the variable from /abcd/efgh/LEG.cfg to $ApID. I suspect the syntax is incorrect in line 6. i.e. my $ApID = $LEDcfg->param(".ApID"). Here i'm calling $LEDcfg and assign to $ApID. Is that the right way to declare the variable taken from some other location

Comment: You don't have to try this out with the "huge script created by my organization leads". Figure out how to do it in a small, separate script then port that into the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you aren't reading the configuration file, and perhaps that is why you don't get any values.

The trick in programming is to know that you are in a good, expected state at each step. Go back to your program and look at each step to check that what you wanted to happen actually did happen. I suspect your problem happens very early in the process and that nothing else can then work.

You have the filename in `$configfile`, but then use `$conffile`:

```
my $confdir = $ENV{CFG_DIR};  
my $configfile = 'LED.cfg'; 
my $LEDcfg = new Config::Simple( filename => "$confdir/$conffile" );
```

Then, after that, you don't do anything to check that you have a valid configuration.

Start by using `strict`, which forces you to declare variables so you can catch those pesky instances where you use the wrong name. Then, once you construct the path, see if it actually exists:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions;

my $conf_dir = ...;
my $conf_file = ...;

my $conf_path = catfile( $conf_dir, $conf_file );
die "Config path <$conf_path> does not exist!" unless -e $conf_path;
```

Once you know that you have an existing file. Note that you have to call the method correctly. The first argument is the path, not `filename`. You can also check that you got what you expected:

```
my $config = Config::Simple->new( $conf_path );
my %vars = $config->vars;

use Data::Dumper;
print "Found config: ", Dumper( \%vars );
```

Furthermore, you say you want to get the value for `ApID`, but then try to access `.ApID`. Maybe that's right, but it looks suspicious and you haven't shown us a sample configuration file. You might add some more debugging output there to check that you get a value.

Once you sort out that part, you can continue with the rest. But, also note that Config::Simple is 15 years old. There are many better, currently supported modules that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Brian. I am simply trying to print the value of ApID from LED.cfg file. I tried below but getting some error. 
`
>cat /amex/lcd/LED.cfg
ApID=ACF_ERTF_DER
>cat test1.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Config::Simple;

  my $confdir = "/amex/lcd"
  $conffile = 'LED.cfg';
  my $LEDcfg = "$configdir/$configfile";
  my $ApID = Config::Simple->($LEDcfg->ApID);
  print "$AppID";
> ./test1.pl
Can't locate Config/Simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /amex/lib/lcd /amex/lib/ /usr/local/lib64/perl5
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test1.pl lib
`

Comment: Notice that you have the same errors in this code, and you didn't try what I showed you in my answer. But, you need to install Config::Simple, and there are plenty of answers on StackOverflow that can help you.

Comment: thanks brian. I have successfully retrieved the value using Config::Simple. I am getting the desired output for ApID value. However i am getting error while trying to run below command inside the another perl script. From below command, I am running CA.sh and parse the output to $pwd. So that this pwd variable is used for further database connectivity. If i run the CA.pl outside the script, i am getting the password of the database user mentioned in the CA.pl. But i am getting error if i add this CA.pl insider the huge perl script. failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a new question on StackOverflow.